# 100 syntax errors on tokens in R.java

Tags: java, android, xml, syntax-error, rjava

There is exactly 100 errors in `R.java` that all say the same error.  The error is the following:

Syntax error on token "10", delete this token

There are red flags everywhere saying not to modify `R.java` and even when I try to, it prompts me to stop.  Then when I still change something it reverts back to the errored code.  The lines that causing errors are below.

```
    public static final int 10ca16=0x7f05084a;
    public static final int 10ca17=0x7f05084b;
    public static final int 10ca18=0x7f05084c;
    public static final int 10ca19=0x7f05084d;
    public static final int 10ca2=0x7f05083c;
    public static final int 10ca20=0x7f05084e;
    public static final int 10ca21=0x7f05084f;
    public static final int 10ca22=0x7f050850;
    public static final int 10ca23=0x7f050851;
    public static final int 10ca24=0x7f050852;
    public static final int 10ca25=0x7f050853;
    public static final int 10ca26=0x7f050854;
    public static final int 10ca27=0x7f050855;
    public static final int 10ca28=0x7f050856;
    public static final int 10ca29=0x7f050857;
    public static final int 10ca3=0x7f05083d;
    public static final int 10ca30=0x7f050858;
```

I just got down inputting 100s and 100s of strings into `strings.xml` since I am trying to localize and support Spanish.  I'm sure it probably has something to do with that.

My question is what exactly is wrong?  My two `strings.xml` files in my `values` and `values-es` folders do not have any errors flagged.

Comment: Are you using numeric ids for the resources?

Comment: Also post a snippet of the code from the strings.xml and your layout file

Comment: Also you said you modified R.java, there is a reason you shouldn't modify it.  This can't be a real question.  It's like asking why my finger hurts when I stick it in a electrical socket.  This should be closed.

Comment: @MarkBasler - Very nonconstructive comment.  Please see the 2 CORRECT answers below on what comments/answers should look like.

Comment: Matt you aren't supposed to modify R.java.  And he modified it.

Comment: And Matt I do know variables aren't supposed to start with a number but he modified a precompiled class that you aren't supposed to touch.

Comment: @MarkBasler - The error had zero relevance with touching `R.java`.  Please see the answer provided below.

Comment: Yeah it did the real way to do that would have been to create a helper class.  That class gets touched and changed by the compiler at run time and modified on the fly.

Comment: Did you notice you had two down votes on this question?  That's why.

Comment: The answer was that the variables started with a number instead of letter/underscore.  The answer had nothing to do with me temporarily altering `R.java` for less than 30 seconds and then it regenerating at runtime.  Not sure of your confusion here.

Comment: Matt I think you are confused.  R.java shouldn't be modified.  Like I said create a helper class for what you are wanting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There are red flags everywhere saying not to modify R.java and even when I try to, it prompts me to stop.

Maybe something was trying to tell you that you shouldn't touch the file.

But that being said:

```
public static final int 10ca16=0x7f05084a;
//                      ^^^^^^
```

Variable names in Java cannot start with a number. This is a restriction that's been on C-derived languages since they were invented.

Start the variable name with an underscore or letter, like `_10ca16` or `ca10_16` (or whatever you prefer).

Comment: Did you see where he said he modified R.java, there's a reason you aren't supposed to modify that.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thank you Michael.

Answer (score 2):

Variable names can't start with a number. If you change the strings to start with a letter instead, it will work.

Comment: Simon did you see the part where he said he modified R.java....not supposed to modify that.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thank you Simon.

Comment: @MarkBasler True, that's why I said "change the strings to start with a letter instead". I could have explained it more in my answer.